# Is RX1 and TX0 the same thing as TX and RX? Will there be a difference in the way I program it?

Tags: pins, atmega328, port-mapping, coding-standards

I have an Arduino.

I'm not sure if RX1 and TX0 the same thing as TX and RX? Will there be a difference in the way I program it?

For example, do I treat RX1 and TX0 as RX and TX in the Arduino IDE when coding?

This is the chip I have. On the chip it says "ProMini R160JAC6v" and when I program it, it programs under 5V 16MHz with ATmega 328. Notice RST RX1 and TX0 are on the top left corner.

[image: ProMini R160JAC6v 5V 16MHz with ATmega 328]

Answer (score 5):

It's not RX1 and TX0 but RXI and TXO

That is receive input and transmit output,

Exactly the same as RX and TX just with the data direction explicitly shown in the lettering.

Comment: No, it is not mnemonical. It is about PIN numbers: 0 for RX and 1 for TX, as seen in the table here: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/. However, you invented a good one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you treat them the same, they are the same pins.

It looks like (in the photo) you're connecting a bluetooth module.
Be careful when uploading your sketch.  If you connect something to TX/RX (pins 0 & 1) it may be necessary to disconnect it for arduino-uploading to work.

You may find it a more convenient solution to declare a SoftwareSerial on different ports and use that for the bluetooth communications.